# Replacing the values of a column with Values of another column in a different Table without having an ID

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have 2 Tables.
1 table has my Data with a code.
The other table is a conversion table, where each code is assigned to a certain text.
I want that text to be in Table 1, my Data table.

Example:

[image: Data]

[image: Table 2, Conversion Table]

i tried this:

[image: SQL Code]

Comment: provide text instead of images it helps you to get faster recommendations

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inner select:

```
update table1 t1
set brandName = (select t2.text from table2 t2 where t1.key = t2.brand);
```